# D3 treemap json data format

Tags: d3.js, treemap

I'm new to d3js. I've gone through several examples of the treemap visualization and  noticed that the data has the same hierarchical structure:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
  "children": [
      ...
   ]
      ...
}
```

But what if I have an array of objects with same set of properties without nesting:

```
[
  { 
   "CourseID": "15.010B",
   "Subject": "15.01",
   "Section": "B",
   "Department": "Managerial Economics",
   "Professor": "Doyle",
      ...
  },
  { 
   "CourseID": "15.010B",
   "Subject": "15.01",
   "Section": "B",
      ...
  },
      ...
]
```

Should I make it hierarchical by myself? Can you provide me with visual treemap example for this type of data format. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

d3's built-in [nest](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Arrays#-nest) feature can easily create this type of hierarchical data for you, for example:

```
var nest = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.Department; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.Subject; })
    .key(function(d) { return d.Section; })
    .entries(_dataset_name_);
```

will create a suitably hierarchical dataset.

Comment: Thanks, but without the "children" attribute in your JSON, you won't get any hierarchical packing, will you? The thing is, I want d3.layout.treemap(data) function make x,y,dx,dy properties in each object for me in order to draw a rectangle for each one.

Comment: The "children" property is just the default.  You can specify whatever property you like for children by setting a custom accessor function via https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Treemap-Layout#wiki-children.

Comment: Thank you, Scott. So it's necessary to have particular property as a children and in this case d3 will compute the x,y,dx,dy properties for me, am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Formatting your JSON into a hierarchical structure can be tedious. I used [Google Refine](https://code.google.com/p/google-refine/wiki/Downloads) which allowed me to import CSV,JSON or Excel files and "refine" them into the JSON structures of my choice. It seem a bit of a pain to set up, but once completed, you will have a tool for manipulating your data into structures of your choice going forward.