# Structure of the JSON flare input for D3.js Treemap Visualization

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, treemap

I am currently working with the [Treemap](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4063582) visualization of D3.js and was hoping to understand how the flare.json used in the example has been organized. Does the format of the json input file need to be in the exact same structure as used in the example. I have an input file from a web crawler with a list of URLs and their respective parent URLs. I tried using something like the following but it won't work and am not sure if it's just the structure that's different or something else.

listURLs.json:

```
{
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
    {"children":"http:\/\/a.wholelottanothing.org","name":"http:\/\/buzz.blogger.com"},              
    {"children":"http:\/\/www.bitworking.org","name":"http:\/\/buzz.blogger.com"},   
    {"children":"http:\/\/blog.computationalcomplexity.org","name":"http:\/\/buzz.blogger.com"},  
    {"children":"http:\/\/www.blogactionday.org","name":"http:\/\/buzz.blogger.com"}, 
    {"children":"http:\/\/www.wikipaintings.org","name":"http:\/\/littlegreeniguana.blogspot.com"}
    ]
}
```

I know this looks very different from the flare.json used in the example but can this work? Also, the input that I am using doesn't include the 'size' parameter which is also probably why the output is blank. How do I use the size here? Can it be dynamically adjusted later in the code? Any help will be most appreciated, I am a D3 novie!

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18322327/d3-treemap-json-data-format) helped when I had a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

The hierarchical data format expected by tree, pack and other D3 hierarchical layouts is expecting "children" to be an array of objects, and traverses that hierarchical data in preparation for formatting your objects for display using layouts. So, you don't want to use "children" to store a single link, instead, you want it to store an array of objects formatted just like the parent object (even if there is only one thing in that array). It's a bit hard to grasp what you're trying to display in your dataset, but my guess is all those websites are under buzz.blogger.com, except the last one, in which case properly formatted hierarchical data would look like this (Note that everything is nested in a root node, which you can name whatever you want):

```
{
 "name": "root node",
 "children": [
  {"name":"http:\/\/buzz.blogger.com", "children": [
   {"name": "http:\/\/www.bitworking.org"},
   {"name": "http:\/\/blog.computationalcomplexity.org"},
   {"name": "http:\/\/www.blogactionday.org"}
   ]
  },
  {"name":"http:\/\/littlegreeniguana.blogspot.com", "children": [
   {"name": "http:\/\/www.wikipaintings.org"}
   ]
  }
 ]
}
```